# FTP command to put a directory to server from local system

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ftp

```
put  filename  will put the file to cureent directory in server.
```

Which command i have to use to move a entire folder/ directory??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mput *
```

ftp can't put directly directory trees, only files.

Comment: Thanks! am going to accept the the answer that there is no answer!!]

Answer (score 13):

You can use `ncftp` software to put directory tree from local to ftp servers.
You need to install this ftp software.

Upload command would be:

```
ncftpput -avR -u <user> -p<password> <ftpserver> <path to put> <local folder>
```

where,

`a` transfer all files in ASCII mode and not in binary.

`v` to see output in verbose mode

`R` to copy folders in recursive mode.

Comment: This was useful. There is an OSX Homebrew bottle for ncftp.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [`sshd`](http://www.openssh.com/) on the remote system, you can probably use [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).

It has built-in compression and all sorts of other goodness:

```
% rsync -chavz --partial --progress --stats test remotehost:
sending incremental file list
test/
test/test.c
         387 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=5/7)
test/test.cpp
         231 100%  225.59kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=4/7)
test/test.new
         253 100%  123.54kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=3/7)
test/test.php
         578 100%  282.23kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=2/7)
test/test.py
         288 100%  140.62kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#5, to-check=1/7)
test/test.sh
          81 100%   26.37kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#6, to-check=0/7)

Number of files: 7
Number of files transferred: 6
Total file size: 1.82K bytes
Total transferred file size: 1.82K bytes
Literal data: 1.82K bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 193
File list generation time: 0.003 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 1.54K
Total bytes received: 130

sent 1.54K bytes  received 130 bytes  159.43 bytes/sec
total size is 1.82K  speedup is 1.09
```

Watch what happens if you run it again and no files have changed...

```
% rsync -chavz --partial --progress --stats test remotehost:
sending incremental file list

Number of files: 7
Number of files transferred: 0
Total file size: 1.82K bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 193
File list generation time: 0.003 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 207
Total bytes received: 13

sent 207 bytes  received 13 bytes  23.16 bytes/sec
total size is 1.82K  speedup is 8.26
```

Answer (score 0):

No way. you must upload each files separate. you can first crawl directories and then upload each file. you have this limit too for delete a directory via ftp.